# How to sync my Windows Phone with iTunes (Windows)?

Tags: sync

I want to sync my music and videos with my iTunes library on Windows 7.

Is it possible? Or must I use some other, Microsoft-specific, bit of software in order to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to sync a Windows Phone on Windows is through Zune. Zune should automatically import your DRM-free iTunes library when you first install it, so you don't have to re-add your files or anything.

Comment: Is it an actual sync (2way) or just an import?
Im trying to decide between android and wp. Android has an app called iSyncr that will do it. In a perfect world I'd like to purchase music from the iTunes Store on whatever device I have so there's no syncing required. It would be a win win for me, apple, and google/Microsoft.

Comment: Zune watches your Windows Music library, which contains the iTunes folder. Adding new songs on iTunes would add them to your Music library, which would add them to Zune.  

iTunes, however, does not automatically watch folders to add/remove songs like Zune does. You can use a program like iTunes Folder Watch for this: http://albumbrowser.klarita.net/itfw.html